# Pandas: Optimal way to MultiIndex columns

Tags: python, pandas

I start with the following `DataFrame`:

```
df_1 = DataFrame({
        "Cat1" : ["a", "b"],
        "Vals1" : [1,2] ,
        "Vals2" : [3,4]
    })
df
```

[image]

I want to get it to look like this:

[image]

And I can do it, with this code:

```
df_2 = (
    pd.melt(df_1, id_vars=["Cat1"])
    .T
)
df_2.columns = (
    pd.MultiIndex
        .from_tuples(
            list(zip(df_2.loc["Cat1", :] , df_2.loc["variable", :])) ,
            names=["Cat1", None]
        )
)
df_2 = (
    df_2
    .loc[["value"], :]
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .sortlevel(0, axis=1)
)
df_2
```

But there are so many steps here that I feel code smell, or at least something vaguely not pandas-idiomatic, as if I'm missing the point of something in the API.  Doing the equivalent for row-based indexes is just one step, for example, via `set_index()`.  (Note that I am aware that the columns equivalent of `set_index()` [is still an open issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5909)).  Is there a better, more official way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `stack()`, `to_frame()`, and `T` for transpose.

```
df_1.set_index('Cat1').stack().to_frame().T


Cat1     a           b      
     Vals1 Vals2 Vals1 Vals2
0        1     3     2     4
```

Comment: Can I give you some advice? Upvote question especially if OP get after your upvote 15+ points - then OP can upvote your solutions ;)

Answer (score 2):

Think about it as a transposed dataframe. Here you go:

```
df.set_index('Cat1').unstack().swaplevel().sort_index().to_frame().T
Out[46]: 
Cat1     a           b      
     Vals1 Vals2 Vals1 Vals2
0        1     3     2     4
```